# Adding A line in a graph

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I have this question about how to add a line in a `ListPlot[]` graph.
I am trying to add a y=4
[image]

I have written the following:

```
ListPlot[{capStock, answerkvector}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> 80]
```

Also bonus questions, how can I make the blue line (capStock) look "nicer"
Thanks!

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "nicer"? Also, it could be good if you could add the data used to generate the plot.

Comment: The data is really big. Should I try sharing a file? By nicer I mean like a more linear line. Instead of bumpy shape.

Comment: Well, I can create a toy-model to show you how to add the $y=4$ line. So, no problem there. But to make a smoother linear line, I think that access to the data might be necessary. I will try to do it using random stuff, and you can let me know what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is showing how to add a horizontal $y=4$ line.

```
data = RandomReal[7, {1000, 2}];
p1 = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> 10];
p2 = Plot[4, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red];

Show[p1, p2]
```

> [image: p1p2]

For the bonus:

I guess you can try something like the following -note that I changed the data to make something smooth and also changed the value of the horizontal to make it more visible.

```
SeedRandom[5]
data = Table[{x - RandomReal[20], x + RandomReal[20]}, {x, -50, 50, 
   1}]; p1 = 
 ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 10];
p2 = Plot[50, {x, -100, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[p1, p2]
```

> [image: p1p2v2]

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a x + b, {a, b}, x];
p3 = Plot[nlm[x], 
  Evaluate@Flatten@{x, Through[{Min, Max}[data[[All, 1]]]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick, Dashed}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.01], Point[data]}]
```

> [image: fit]

```
Show[p1, p3]
```

> [image: final]

Comment: Worked. Thanks!

Comment: @diegor glad I was able to help :-)

Comment: @diegor I added some code to hopefully help you get a smoother line, but since I don't have your data, I am not sure if it will work. Essentially, I did a fit and plotted that with the rest of the stuff :-)

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much